# How to make Ansible Dynamic Inventory work with Google Cloud Platform (Google Compute Engine), GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I used Ansible to create a gce cluster following the guideline at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html

And at the end of the GCE creations, I used the `add_host` Ansible module to register all instances in their corresponding groups. `e.g. gce_master_ip`

But then when I try to run the following tasks after the creation task, they would not work:

```
- name: Create redis on the master
  hosts: gce_master_ip
  connection: ssh
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  vars_files:
    - gcp_vars/secrets/auth.yml
    - gcp_vars/machines.yml
  roles:
    - { role: redis, tags: ["redis"] }
```

Within the `auth.yml` file I already provided the service account email, path to the json credential file and the project id. But apparently that's not enough. I got errors like below:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

This a typical ssh username and credentials not permitted or not provided. In this case I would say I did not setup anything of the username and private key for the `ssh` connection that Ansible will use to do the connecting.

Is there anything I should do to make sure the corresponding credentials are provided to establish the connection?

During my search I think one question just briefly mentioned that you could use the `gcloud compute ssh...` command. But is there a way I could specify in Ansible to not using the classic `ssh` and use the gcloud one?

Answer (score 13):

To have Ansible SSH into a GCE instance, you'll have to supply an SSH username and private key which corresponds to the the SSH configuration available on the instance.

So the question is: If you've just used the [`gcp_compute_instance`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_module.html#parameters) Ansible module to create a fresh GCE instance, is there a convenient way to configure SSH on the instance without having to manually connect to the instance and do it yourself?

For this purpose, GCP provides a couple of ways to [automate and manage key distribution](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#provide-key) for GCE instances.
For example, you could use the [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) feature. To use OS Login with Ansible:

1. When creating the instance using Ansible, Enable OS Login on the target instance by setting the "enable-oslogin" metadata field to "TRUE" via the [metadata parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_module.html#parameters).
2. Make sure the Service Account attached to the instance that runs Ansible have both the [roles/iam.serviceAccountUser and roles/compute.osLoginAdmin](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users) permissions.
3. Either generate a new or choose an existing [SSH keypair](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/#creating-an-ssh-key-pair-for-user-authentication) that will be deployed to the target instance.
4. [Upload the public key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#add_oslogin_keys) for use with OS Login: This can be done via `gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file [KEY_FILE_PATH] --ttl [EXPIRE_TIME]` (where `--ttl` specifies how long you want this public key to be usable - for example, `--ttl 1d` will make it expire after 1 day)
5. Configure Ansible to use the Service Account's user name and the private key which corresponds to the public key uploaded via the `gcloud` command. For example by overriding the `ansible_user` and `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` inventory parameters, or by passing `--private-key` and `--user` parameters to `ansible-playbook`.

The service account username is the `username` value returned by the `gcloud` command above.

Also, if you want to automatically set the `enable-oslogin` metadata field to "TRUE" across all instances in your GCP project, you can simply add a project-wide metadata entry. This can be done in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata) under "Compute Engine > Metadata".